# How do I get want anything to work with xlswrite in octave?

Tags: octave

I want anything to work with xlswrite in octave. Eventually I want to be able to put a cell array containing but really anything working at all would be a start.

I've put in the following lines as this is the simplest case I could think of:

```
 array1 = [0 9 10]

 cellarray1 = num2cell(array1)

 xlswrite ('/home/willubuntu/acpimrepo/bob.xlsx', cellarray1)
```

Then I get this error:

error: `xlswrite' undefined near line 9 column 1

I've tried this:

```
 xlswrite ('/home/willubuntu/acpimrepo/bob.xlsx','cellarray1')
```

And get the same error:

error: `xlswrite' undefined near line 9 column 1

I've tried removing the space between xlswrite and the opening parenthesis - same error.

I've tried using array1 and not cellarray1 and got the same error (with both parenthesis options).

I've tried removing the directory from the file name and get a very slightly different error:

error: `xlswrite' undefined near line 10 column 1

What is going on? Why doesn't xlswrite work? What piece of pedantry am I missing?

Please remember that if you say anything too sophisticated, it will go over my head. Remember I am clueless and at the end of my tether.

Comment: This might be an install issue related to the io package according to [this](http://domainmathide.freeforums.org/i-can-not-export-data-to-excel-file-t27.html) and [this](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fforum.ubuntuusers.de%2Ftopic%2Foctave-3-4-installation-unter-ubuntu-10-%2F) (Google translated from German).

Comment: Yeah, it isn't installed - I spent hours trying to work this out. That is annoying. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use a recent Octave version you would see

```
octave:1> xlswrite
warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O
(.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods .dbf .wk1 etc.)
are provided in the io package.  See <http://octave.sf.net/io/>.
```

which guides you to the right direction.

Even a quick search on http://wiki.octave.org/Main_Page would solve this. Perhaps you should spend some minutes with a search machine or the manual and the wiki instead of moaning how annoying and boring GNU Octave is.

Comment: Sorry for being a beginner. I've only been using octave for a few days. Until yesterday I wasn't even aware the octave I downloaded wasn't the most up to date. I did spend a lot of time (hours actually) trying to search for info on this but if you know nothing and you aren't getting a useful error message - it's not easy.

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: I don't know on which system you want to use GNU Octave so I can't point you to the right place but wiki.octave.org is one of the main places to find infos together with octave.org. Then there is an IRC channel (where you might get instant answers) and the help mailinglist.